# Como iniciar o waitress-server em Background?

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tentando iniciar o servidor waitress-serve em uma aplicação Flask. Para isso eu uso:

```
waitress-serve --call --listen=0.0.0.0:5000 app:create_app
```

No entanto quando o servidor inicia ele trava a saída do console. Como posso iniciar o serviço em Background, para liberar o console e continuar uma sequencia de comandos, caso eu precise, por exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o seguinte comando:

```
waitress-serve --call --listen=0.0.0.0:5000 app:create_app >> log.txt &
```

Desse jeito, você redireciona a saída de log para `log.txt` e `&` força rodar em background. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Apenas melhorando a resposta do amigo [@igor-cavalcanti](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/357990/como-iniciar-o-waitress-server-em-background/357991#357991).
Se você só rodar com `>> log.txt &` não garante que irá continuar rodando em background após você encerrar sua sessão no terminal, só irá direcionar a STOUT para o arquivo `log.txt`, e estará ativo até você encerrar sua sessão. Quando você fechar o terminal, o processo é terminado também.

O mais correto nesse caso, para rodar em background - mesmo após terminar a sessão - seria utilizar `nohup`

> De acordo com o [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup):
>
> > nohup é um comando do UNIX que permite executar programa de uma forma
> >     "desconectada" da sessão atual. Ou seja, se o usuário fizer logout, o
> >     comando continuará a rodar em segundo plano, emitindo sua saída para o
> >     arquivo nohup.out

Ou seja, mesmo que você desconecte do terminal, seu comando irá continuar rodando no servidor, que acredito ser o motivo pelo qual você deseja isso.
Assim, o comando final seria:

```
nohup waitress-serve --call --listen=0.0.0.0:5000 app:create_app &
```

Note que não há o `>> log.txt` uma vez que o próprio `nohup` irá salvar a saída no arquivo `nohup.out`